# Ajax call returning null: Phonegap Android

Tags: android, jquery, cordova

I have an Ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
  url : 192.168.4.111/.....,
  type : "GET",
  async : "true",
  username : username,
  password : password,
  success : controller.handleSuccess,
  error : controller.handleError,
  beforeSend : function(xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', "fetch");
    xhr.withCredentials = true;
  }
});
```

But this doesn't work, I get a response, but there are on data. The response is "null". 
Can anyone help me? If I call the same html project in the browser of the android emulator, there are no problems, only when I want to create my own project with Phonegap.

Comment: The response is `null` when handled by `controller.handleSuccess`? Have you tried without changinf request header? Why `async : "true"` instead of `async : true`?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you tested it on android. Note that make this work in browser you have to use JSONP or another crossdomain techniqe.